# setTargetFragment() getTargetFragment() deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I am using deprecated method `setTargetFragment()` `getTargetFragment()` . Using setTargetFragment(target) lets the "called" fragment know where to send the result and calling onActivityResult() manually in this case. check caller fragment like this

```
     if (getTargetFragment() instanceof FragmentA ){
         // Some Code
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(requestCode, Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
       }
```

Starting new fragment like this

```
Media_Gallery gallery = new Media_Gallery();
gallery.setTargetFragment(AddMedia.this,104);
    
FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction=getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                            fragmentTrasaction.addToBackStack("Image");
                                            fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.Main_Layout,gallery,"Image");
fragmentTrasaction.commit();
```

As i am targeting latest API (33) It's stop working for me. Trying to get logic from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings#split_your_hierarchy_into_multiple_screens) but it's bit confusing to me. Can anyone help me understand how can i replace deprecated method to

Comment: i'm not aware of targetSdkVersion 33 changing the behavior of dialog fragments as dialog fragments / target fragments are an AndroidX concept, why would the targetSdkVersion affect this logic? genuinely asking I'm not aware of this change https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setTargetFragment(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,int)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce may be you are right but `setTargetFragment() getTargetFragment()` deprecated as we all know and it will not work in future release. I am bit confuse to find it's alternative.

Comment: Did you read the [guide specifically around returning results between fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result)?

Comment: @Ritu where did you see that it won't work in the future?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i think deprecated means it will remove in future version of android. `An element may be deprecated for any of several reasons, for example, its usage is likely to lead to errors; it may be changed incompatibly or removed in a future version; it has been superseded by a newer, usually preferable alternative; or it is obsolete.`

Comment: So technically target fragments work just fine for now, as the reason why it's deprecated is that Google wanted to force devs to use the not-type-safe `FragmentResultListener`, but that alone doesn't mean target fragments stopped working, nor that they will be removed any time in the near future.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes you are right. But it would be better to move out from deprecated code in our upcoming release. Is there any workaround you know?